# Magento paypal express - 'Unable to place the order'

Tags: magento, paypal, checkout

I am using PayPal Express payment method. I issue I am having is when you proceed checkout with PayPal, it redirects you to Paypal. You login or guest checkout (using master/visa card) and after pressing continue it redirects you back to the Order Review page in Magento. So far all good. Now when you press 'Place Order' button, it shows 'Unable to place the order' error message. Weird thing is it has created the order in Magento and I've PayPal debug mode enable which show payment status to successful (money is out of the account). But for some reason it doesn't redirect to success page.

I am trying to debug it and looking in `app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Controller/Express/Abstract.php`
I have planted logs in 'placeOrderAction()' and noticed it doesn't go past:
`$this->_checkout->place($this->_initToken());`
When traced it further `$this->submitNominalItems();` call seems to be the culprit in 
`app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php`

I am just lost at this point. It just does't go past here. Any ideas?

Comment: I have been dealing with this for the last half an hour - wondering what I have done in development to cause it.  Checked live site, Paypal were actually having problems it seems. Be aware it might be nothing to do with your install, it might be an issue at the Paypal end.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this issue ?